# Changing splash image on Xamarin Forms application

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms

I have an application the is built using the Xamarin forms template in Visual Studio 2017. It works well, but I've wanted to change the image on the launch screen.

I have an image which is high resolution and want to fit to size, but instead its too big and you can only see part of the image when the ios app loads.

Here is the code, I've changed the image name to TEST1.png in the LaunchScreen.Storyboard xamarin.ios project

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<document type="com.apple.InterfaceBuilder3.CocoaTouch.Storyboard.XIB" version="3.0" toolsVersion="6245" systemVersion="13F34" targetRuntime="iOS.CocoaTouch" propertyAccessControl="none" useAutolayout="YES" useTraitCollections="YES" initialViewController="X5k-f2-b5h">
<dependencies>
    <plugIn identifier="com.apple.InterfaceBuilder.IBCocoaTouchPlugin" version="6238"/>
</dependencies>
<scenes>
    <!--View Controller-->
    <scene sceneID="gAE-YM-kbH">
        <objects>
            <viewController id="X5k-f2-b5h" sceneMemberID="viewController">
                <layoutGuides>
                    <viewControllerLayoutGuide type="top" id="Y8P-hJ-Z43"/>
                    <viewControllerLayoutGuide type="bottom" id="9ZL-r4-8FZ"/>
                </layoutGuides>
                <view key="view" contentMode="scaleToFill" id="yd7-JS-zBw">
                    <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="600" height="600"/>
                    <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask" widthSizable="YES" heightSizable="YES"/>
                    <subviews>
                        <imageView userInteractionEnabled="NO" contentMode="scaleToFill" misplaced="YES" image="test1.png" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="23">
                            <rect key="frame" x="270" y="270" width="60" height="60"/>
                            <rect key="contentStretch" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="0.0" height="0.0"/>
                        </imageView>
                    </subviews>
                    <color key="backgroundColor" red="0.20392156862745098" green="0.59607843137254901" blue="0.85882352941176465" alpha="1" colorSpace="calibratedRGB"/>
                    <constraints>
                        <constraint firstItem="23" firstAttribute="centerY" secondItem="yd7-JS-zBw" secondAttribute="centerY" priority="1" id="39"/>
                        <constraint firstItem="23" firstAttribute="centerX" secondItem="yd7-JS-zBw" secondAttribute="centerX" priority="1" id="41"/>
                    </constraints>
                </view>
            </viewController>
            <placeholder placeholderIdentifier="IBFirstResponder" id="XAI-xm-WK6" userLabel="First Responder" sceneMemberID="firstResponder"/>
        </objects>
        <point key="canvasLocation" x="349" y="339"/>
    </scene>
</scenes>
<resources>
    <image name="test1.png" width="180" height="180"/>
</resources>
```

Is there any way i can resize the image without changing the actual image itself?

Thanks

Comment: Follow [this guide](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/application_fundamentals/working_with_images/launch-screens/). It shows all the required steps.

Comment: Did the image show out of the screen? Can you provide a screenshot of your splash screen?

Comment: thanks all, the guides are very helpful

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have set the `ContentMode` of the Image to "`scaleToFill`". This will make your image to scale such that it will go beyond the target area untill the smallest side fits the flush.

Change the `ContentMode` to "`scaleAspectFit`" for that Image and see it it works for you.

These Links would be helpful to understand the ContentMode in detail:

[Link 1](https://useyourloaf.com/blog/stretching-redrawing-and-positioning-with-contentmode/)

[Link 2](http://blogs.innovationm.com/image-handling-in-ios/)

Comment: Worked great thanks.Is there somewhere i can find the documentation on this? Just so i can see all the configurations for ContentMode etc?

Comment: I Edited my answer with added links.